# Geoserver homebrew automatic launch OS X 10.10

Tags: homebrew, osx-yosemite, geoserver

I have installed Geoserver with homebrew on OS X 10.10. I can not find any launchagent file. So I tried to make my own and put it in ~/Users/myuser/Library/LaunchAgents.

I called this homebrew.mxcl.geoserver.plist

Here is the content. It does not work. Any Ideas? I now have to start Geoserver with

**geoserver /path/to/geoserver_data_dir/data**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.geoserver</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>geoserver</string>
    <string>/Library/WebServer/geoserver_data_dir/data</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Try using the full path to the executable: `<string>/usr/local/bin/geoserver</string>` (assuming that it's installed there).

Comment: Thanks but that did not help. Strange that the same command works in terminal:  `/usr/local/bin/geoserver /Library/WebServer/geoserver_data_dir/data`

Comment: If `geoserver` happens to be a shell script that depends on certain environment variables, it may not work as a launch agent (without first setting those env vars in your .plist). Try setting `<Debug>` to `<true/>` and check the logs (I think it will log in `/var/log/system.log`) to see if any errors are being logged.

Comment: I added a debug and it just said the service is to be running all the time. But it is in fact working with the plist with the full path. I think I just had not killed the running service. So just add this as an answer and I will vote you up!